# re.findall() function python

Tags: python, python-re

Can you please help me to understand the following line of the code:

```
import re 
a= re.findall('[А-Яа-я-\s]+', string)
```

I am a bit confused with the pattern that has to be found in the string. Particularly, a string should start with `A` and end with any string in-between `A` and `я`, should be separated by `-` and space, but what does the second term `Яа` stand for?

Comment: `Яа` doesn't stand for anything. It's two ranges, `А-Я` and `а-я`. The first is the uppercase Cyrillic letters, the second is lowercase letters.

Comment: Why do you think it should start with `А`? That's inside a character set, so it's the start of a character range, not the start of the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[         ]      any of the characters in here
 А-Я             any character from А and Я, inclusive
    а-я          any character between а and я, inclusive
       -         the character -   (this is ambiguous; it should only be at the very start or end of the class)
        \s       any whitespace character
           +     at least one of the preceding class of characters

[А-Яа-я-\s]+     at least one character between А and Я (uppercase or lowercase), a dash, or whitespace
```

the `[]` is called a "class" in regex, and it's basically meant to say "any of the characters inside here is valid". And then `+` means "at least one occurrence of the preceding character/class".
Python has a [Regular Expressions HowTo](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto) that you might find useful to read through.